# Linked List Loop Iterations alter global variable head

Tags: c, loops, pointers, linked-list, text-files

When I attempt to establish my linked list using a while loop, the second iteration of the loop changes the global head. The values are read in from a file, into a string (buffer) and then tokenized to establish the values of .name and .id . The bottom code is used to establish the global head.

`struct node{
    char name[50];
    int id;
    struct node* next;
}*head;`

Using print statements, I have devised that head.name and head.id are altered in the second iteration of the loop. If anyone has any suggestions, please offer as they are much appreciated.

```
int read(){
char buffer[500];
char name[50];
int id;
struct node *temp;
head = NULL;
FILE *fp = fopen("AssignmentOneInput.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Cant read.\n");
    return 0;
}
fgets(buffer, 500, fp);
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
strcpy(head->name, strtok(buffer, ","));
head->id = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
temp = head;
printf("%s\n", head->name);
printf("%d\n", head->id);
while(!feof(fp)){
    fgets(buffer, 500, fp);
    printf("%s\n", head->name);
    printf("%d\n", head->id);
    temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(temp->name, strtok(buffer, ","));
    temp->id = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
    temp = temp->next;
    if(temp == NULL){
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
}}
```

The file AssignmentOneInput.txt contains values stored in the following format though there are about 20 instead of the given 1:

```
George Washington, 2345678
```

Comment: before this line: 'temp = head;' need to set the next field to null: head->next = NULL;

Comment: 1) feof() is not set until after actually trying to read past the end of the file.  Therefore, it should never be used at the top of a loop as a loop-exit control.  2) The code is making the assumption that there is 'at least' one complete record in the input file.  This can/will lead to a code failure. 3) any call to malloc() needs to always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful (!= NULL)

Comment: 1) best to use the fgets() as the control for the while loop 2) make head as a special case (check for head=NULL) for allocating/setting the first entry in the linked list.

Comment: in the while loop, this line: 'temp = temp->next;' should be immediately before filling any fields based on offsets from 'temp', rather than after setting/overlaying the current values in those fields.  strongly suggest always set the next field to NULL when setting the other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `temp=temp->next`  ***before*** assigning `temp->name` and `temp->id`  rather than after doing so otherwise you are overwriting the previous node's data.

Comment: Thank you! It is always the over-sights.